# Do I need ctags installed if I want to use YCM?

Tags: vim

I'm new to Vim and at this moment search the ways jumping to definitions (my lang set is Go, CSS/Sass, HTML, JS). As I far I understand, ctags is the most popular solution here. However I'm going to install YCM, which is offer something similar: `GoToDeclaration` and `GoToDefinition` (unfortunately, for C-family only). I want to understand how YCM is related to ctags. So does YCM use its own mechanism to detect actual definitions or it uses ctags to provide this feature? Or in other words, do I need ctags installed if I want to use YCM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [YouCompleteMe](https://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/) only collects identifiers from the files you visit.

If you want it to collect identifiers from your whole project then you will need [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) and put `let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_tags_files = 1` in your vimrc.